# webpy and CherryPyWSGIServer

Tags: python

I'm using the bottom piece of code for my program http://webpy.org/cookbook/ssl and when I connect to my python server through https all is well. Then when I go to connect to my server as http it does not connect as expected.
But then when I go back to https I get a time out every time and I have to restart my comp so I can connect again.
Can anyone help me with where to start on this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your nginx, or apache server configuration file, you need to redirect the page to https all the time, or handle the http properly.  for example if somebody hits my server I permanently redirect to the https every time like this in Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
}
```

You will also need to define your webpy application handling.  I ended up using Ubuntu, Nginx, uWSGI with webpy and my site works really well.  Hopefully this helps.  I was doing the exact same thing as you until I found this site:

http://fartersoft.com/blog/2012/02/10/deployment-of-web-py-applications-using-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu/

Which helped me get started.  I hope it helps you.